# Why is PHP session info not persisting through browser restarts, even when the cookie and PHPSESSID persists?

Tags: php, session

Logins on a PHP site I am working on are managed by session cookies which store the userid in the session.  This works fine until the browser is closed, at which point the userid information seems to be being lost.

I've set the gc and the cookie keepalive time each to seven days, and the php session settings are as follows (set via .htaccess):

```
session.use_cookies On  On
session.cookie_lifetime 604800  0
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  604800  1440
session.gc_probability  0   0
```

I can verify with Chrome and Firebug that PHPSESSID does have a lifetime of seven days and that it is persisting between browser restarts.  However, session variables such as the userid are definitely not being preserved (I can use var_dump on a separate page to verify this).  What could be causing session variables to be deleted between browser restarts, if gc and cookie lifetimes are being set properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem ended up being with the hosting provider, Rackspace Cloud.  Rackspace Cloud Sites saves $_SESSION information per-server by default but does not attempt to direct the same user to the same server between browser restarts.  I'll have to set up a database-based session system or store the session files somewhere else.

My question might have been unclear because of the conflict between "session cookie" (a cookie that only lasts until browser restart) and the $_SESSION information which is supposed to persist until garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't get "session" and "cookies" mixed up. A session will only persist while the browser remains open. Cookies will stay until they expire regardless of if the browser is closed.

Check out this page for some guidance: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp or the official documentation at: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: My understanding was that the $_SESSION information should persist between browser restarts as long as the PHPSESSID stays the same and is being sent to the server from the browser every time?

Comment: The browser won't automatically send the PHPSESSID as it will loose it when it is shut down. Try $_COOKIES instead.

Answer (score 0):

By default session cookies are deleted when the browser is closed. You have to take other measures to persist - which is why you see "Remember me" as an option since it's not expected behavior.